# How to "break out" of a JQuery color box

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I have a JQuery `colorbox()` using an iframe, and there is a `<form>` in that (e.g. login form), then:

- If the submission of the form is **not successful** (e.g. mandatory field empty) then the form should be re-displayed with the error **in the iframe**
- If the form is **successful** (e.g. password correct), the **surrounding page** should be reloaded with the result

Only the server request can know if the submission is successful or not (e.g. password correct for a login form), therefore one cannot use a `target=` parameter on the `<form>` tag. (As that must be set on the requesting page, where the success of the response is not yet known.)

How should one go about achieving that? Right now I do the following:

- The `<form>` has no particular "target", i.e. the result is displayed in the iframe
- If the form submission is unsuccessful, re-display the form in the iframe (the simple case)
- If the form submission is successful then display a "response" page in the iframe, which contains Javascript, to refresh the whole page.

The Javascript looks like the following (the `wicket:id="link"` means that the web framework adds a `href=` to the link, to specify the resulting page which should be displayed in the whole browser window).

```
<a wicket:id="link" id="linkToSuccessPage" target="_top"></a>
<script>
  $(function() {
    top.$.colorbox.close();
    top.location.href =
      document.getElementById("linkToSuccessPage").getAttribute("href");
  });
</script>
```

The trouble with this approach is, firstly it feels inelegant, but it creates an odd visual effect. The colorbox firstly closes, then there this redirect happens. The other option is not to close the colorbox, but then the contents of the colorbox gets replaced by a blank page while the redirect happens.

Any better ways? This must be a common problem, must have a common elegant solution?

P.S. I have to use the **iframe** method of the colorbox (rather than JQuery taking the form and placing it in a `<div>` in the page) for the following reasons: the web framework I'm using (Wicket) submits forms to a relative URL. The relative URL in the `<form>` is relative to the URL of the page containing the form (= the colorbox contents). If a `<div>` is used, then this form is inserted into the surrounding page which has a different URL, therefore the relative URLs in the form submission do not work.

Answer (score 2):

I think you will still be able to do this without using an iframe, which will allow you to use inline content for your colorbox windows.  Although this suggestion could be adapted for iframes, it's a lot cleaner when using inline content.

First, use [this jQuery ajax form plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#getting-started) to manage the flow of form submission. This will allow you to manage your success/error code without loading anything extra to, as you mentioned, refresh the page or reload the form. In your docReady, instantiate the ajax form like this:

```
$('#login').ajaxForm({
    beforeSubmit: onSubmitForm,
    error: onServerResponse,
    success: onServerResponse,
    url: "site.com"
});
```

Then you just do what you need to do in those 3 callbacks (all in the context of the parent page). Because you are defining the url here, whatever wicket does with the action attribute of the form won't matter. In fact, the html code for the form does not change except for the fact that now you can omit the action attribute.

With the use of inline colorboxes, switching between them while maintaining their data state (if any) is easy. First, assuming we'll give all of our colorbox links the classname "colorboxLink", we also need this in the docReady:

```
$(".colorboxLink").colorbox({
    inline:true
});
```

And in a hidden div, set up all the colorboxes (one of which is your form):

```
<div style="display:none">
    <form id="login" method="post"> 
        Username: <input type="text" name="username" /> <br>
        Password: <input type="password" name="password" /> 
        <input type="submit" value="Go" />
    </form>

    <div id="error">
        Error message.<br>
        <a class="colorboxLink" href="#login">&laquo; Back</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

So, the first colorbox window would open with a link, back/forward/other windows can be opened by links inside the colorboxes (as demonstrated in the "error" div), and to open colorboxes in a function:

```
$.colorbox({
    open:true,
    href: "#error",
    inline:true
});
```

You will also be able to avoid that flicker when changing windows because the colorbox is never fully closed.

Check out a complete example at [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DonamiteIsTNT/ACC44/2/).